# How to run a Sbt Packaged Jar using java -jar or java -cp command?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, packaging

So I have a very simple SBT program.

I'm currently trying to run it, in the same folder as the jar file I've created, using the following command:

```
java -cp "scala-library.jar:myproject_2.11-0.1.jar" Main 3/4
```

Main is the name of the object that contains the main method (I haven't done
an "extends App" this time).  Main doesn't sit in any package or anything, just in the main/scala folder.  3/4 is just a program argument.

I'm getting back "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" again and again no matter what I try and change.  Are there any Scala heads that can help me?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I know of to build an executable program with SBT is to use the "sbt-pack" plugin. Put `addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-pack" % "0.10.1")` in your 'project/plugins.sbt' file, invoke with `sbt pack`, and run with `target/pack/bin/<project_name>`. See the project [github repo](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack) for details. Sorry I can't address the specifics of the question.